# Сайт Alexa.com

Tags: seo

Собственно занимаясь вопросом, как двигать сайт, обнаружил, что многие сервисы проверяют как обычно: PR и тИЦ, а так же количество ссылок с `Alexa.com`. `Alexa.com` - что это такое, с чем это едят и есть ли смысл заморачиваться? В планах на будущие посещения из-за бугра тоже желательны.

UPD: Просьба писать по делу)

Comment: хорошо, а если ориентироваться за бугор(в сутки где то 5-10 переходов есть на текущий момент, при этом не поисковые боты) кроме регистрации сайта у них, как лучшим образом подогнать мету, чтобы не испортить текущую статистику для русско язычных поисковых запросов?

Answer (score 4):

Alexa собирает данные о посещениях от пользователей, которые установили Alexa Toolbar и формирует статистику. Соответственно на основе переходов между сайтами может накапливать информацию о ссылках.

Что касается ссылок, то учитывая, что данные фиксируются только при переходе пользователя, реальной картины ссылочной массы от Alexa получить невозможно. В статистику наверняка не будут попадать ссылки Sape и подобные по одной простой причине — посетители по ним не ходят.

> есть ли смысл замарачиваться?

У Вас стоит Alexa Toolbar? У меня нет. И я не знаю знакомых, кто бы им пользовался. В Рунете, IMHO, Alexa Toolbar не популярен, а значит и смысла нет заморачиваться (морока — *разг.* утомительная, неприятная работа, суета).

Comment: @Kanvi, а у меня давно стоит Alexa-тулбар и знаю еще людей. Очень удобно, что можно сразу видеть популярность незнакомого сайта.